# ASP.NET MVC ViewPage execution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am (roughly) tracing the steps that are taken to generate a view once you call `return View();` from within a controller method.

Thus far I have gotten these steps:

1. Call View()
2. A ViewResult is created with the ViewData from the Controller being passed to it.
3. ViewResult.ExecuteResult() is called.
4. From this point I know that the ViewData is then passed once again to the ViewContext property of the ViewPage object.
5. Magic happens and the ViewPage is sent to the output stream.

There are a lot of steps missing here, does anybody know of a good resource that traces the execution flow?

Cheers!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always [download](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742) the source and step through the code to get a better look at what is going on.